# Error 419 using pusher private channels connection in service worker

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I have an Laravel App and I'm using pusher (and laravel echo) to deliver some notifications to logged in users. Right now each tab consumes one pusher connection so I'm trying to setup this inside a service worker so one user consumes only one connection.

It's not that hard to setup the service worker but what confuses me is the auth/session part. To subscribe to a private channel you need to call an auth endpoint. This endpoint fails on service worker due to the lack of a csrf token.

Is it safe to remove csrf protection to this specific route? or is there a better way to auth users inside a service worker that I'm not aware of?